# Exception has occurred: FileNotFoundError (PIL)

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to modify images in a folder using PIL, but when I run debugging I get a

```
"Exception has occurred: FileNotFoundError
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'page_1.jpg'"
```

The 'page_1.jpg' is the file I'm interested in. Additionally, I'm using the os library to specify the path. Here's the code, not sure what is going on since it is seeing my file but can't find it.

I have run into this problem while doing the first part of pdf to image conversion and found that if I only include two folders like `"/home/folder"` it would work.

I am using ubuntu 18.04 and python 3.6. 
Thanks for your time.

```
from pdf2image import convert_from_path 
import os
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter
converted = r'/path/to folder'
modified = r'/path/ to folder'
for f in os.listdir(converted):
    if f.endswith('.pdf'):
        pages = convert_from_path(f, 500)
        image_counter = 1
        for page in pages:
         filename = "Converted/page_" + str(image_counter) + ".jpg"
         page.save(filename, 'JPEG')
         image_counter = image_counter + 1
for i in os.listdir(modified):
    if i.endswith('.jpg'):
        filename2 = "path/to folder"
        g = Image.open(i)
        g.filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur()).save(filename2)`enter code here`
```

Comment: `os.listdir()` returns a list of just filenames, without the full directory path.  You'll have to combine the filename with the directory, otherwise you're trying to open that filename in the current directory where it (presumably) doesn't exist.

Comment: How does one do that? Can you point me in the right direction? could i use an os.path method? Thanks again.

Comment: `os.path.join(modified,i)`